# Server Move to AWS Cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, migration, rackspace-cloud

I'm wondering specifically is there way to migrate `Centos6.3 server` from `Rackspace to AWS` cloud, Server image is 268.92 GB Uncompressed.

I've done the sync processes before and it didn't work so I wanted to spin up the exact same instance. I also tried the newer libraries of the platform we are running but it failed.

This is essentially what i need to run `https://github.com/knmnyn/ParsCit`. Is there's another way to get that running on the dev machine to updated the repo on?
can anyone Help me with this?